# Persistent configuration of two screens

Tags: xorg, configuration, monitors

I want to configure two screens side by side and want the configuration to **persist** a system restart. (I'm using `xfce` on Xubuntu 12.)

I've inspected old questions and the answers mentioned `arandr` and `xrandr`, and so I did create the (working) shell script that calls `xrandr` with appropriate options and arguments to fit my needs. Now I can place that script in some profile so that it will become active with every login.

My question is; is it possible to configure twin-screens in some system config file so that I need not have a `xrandr` based script executed each time?

As far as my investigation goes, the config file could be `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`, and the file contains sensible information for my twin-screen setup. But that configuration seems to be ignored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution that solved the issue for me (for Xubuntu 12):

In directory `/etc/X11/Xsession.d/` create a file `45-custom_xrandr-settings` (with Xubuntu 13 its name would have to be `45x11-custom_xrandr-settings`). The content of the file is (for my case; adjust the definitions as necessary):

```
# The IDs of the screens
INTERNAL_OUTPUT="DVI-1"
EXTERNAL_OUTPUT="DVI-0"

# EXTERNAL_LOCATION, which can be one of: left, right, above, below
EXTERNAL_LOCATION="left"

case "$EXTERNAL_LOCATION" in
   left|LEFT)
       EXTERNAL_LOCATION="--left-of $INTERNAL_OUTPUT"
       ;;  
   right|RIGHT)
       EXTERNAL_LOCATION="--right-of $INTERNAL_OUTPUT"
       ;;  
   top|TOP|above|ABOVE)
       EXTERNAL_LOCATION="--above $INTERNAL_OUTPUT"
       ;;  
   bottom|BOTTOM|below|BELOW)
       EXTERNAL_LOCATION="--below $INTERNAL_OUTPUT"
       ;;  
   *)
       EXTERNAL_LOCATION="--left-of $INTERNAL_OUTPUT"
       ;;  
esac

xrandr | grep $EXTERNAL_OUTPUT | grep " connected "
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    xrandr --output $INTERNAL_OUTPUT --auto --output $EXTERNAL_OUTPUT --auto $EXTERNAL_LOCATION
else
    xrandr --output $INTERNAL_OUTPUT --auto --output $EXTERNAL_OUTPUT --off
fi
```

Installed in the above specified directory this configuration file will then be executed automatically when the X session is started.